# apex:outputPanel rendered logic

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to render some content in a Visualforce email if specific boolean fields are true. I have 6 boolean fields I'd like to verify.

Using apex:outputPanel I'm able to do the following:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered ="{!relatedto.Agency__c}">
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out the syntax to check each additional boolean field. I've tried 14(!) different combos.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!relatedto.Agency __c} || {!relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c}">  
<apex:outputPanel rendered="({!relatedto.Agency __c} || {!relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c})"> 
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!relatedto.Agency __c} || {!relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c}"> 
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="(!relatedto.Agency __c || !relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c)">  
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{relatedto.Agency __c || relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c}"> 
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="OR(relatedto.Agency __c, relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c)"> 
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{OR(relatedto.Agency __c, relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c)}"> 
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{OR(!relatedto.Agency __c, !relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c)}">  
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{IF(OR(relatedto.Agency __c, relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c))}">   
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="OR(!relatedto.Agency __c, !relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c)}"> 
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="!OR({relatedto.Agency__c},{relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c})"> 
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="OR({relatedto.Agency__c},{relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c})"> 
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="!OR({!relatedto.Agency__c},{!relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c})">
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic frame of a Visualforce expression is `{! }`. You use it only at the outermost level of an attribute.

The `!` character is *also* used as a Boolean negation *within* an expression.

From your examples, if looks like the form you want is this:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! OR(relatedto.Agency__c, relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c) }">
```

This is equivalent to an expression with the `||` Boolean OR operator:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! relatedto.Agency__c || relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c }">
```

Should you need to negate one of your Booleans, you'd prefix it with `!`:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! OR(relatedto.Agency__c, !relatedto.Food_bev_manufacturers__c) }">
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The whole {!  } thing really confuses me. I will have to read the docs and do Trailhead. Appreciate your swift assistance.

Comment: Just remember that any attribute where you want to use an expression is `attribute="{! STUFF_HERE }"`. You only worry about the `STUFF_HERE`.